# Appending two pointers of different data types to a single memory block

Tags: c, sockets, pointers

I'm currently working on both the sending & receiving side of a socket connection in C and running into a situation where I need to **sometimes** send a specific data type (let's call it **custom_data_type**) that must be recognized from the receiver.

From my research, I'm pretty sure that the receiver can't actually make sense of the received data bytes to know their exact data type. So I am trying to implement a sort of a "string identifier" from the sender and append that identifier to the end of the custom_data_type, so that when the receiver sees that string identifier, it should know that the received data bytes are of custom_data_type. Here's a snippet of what I have in mind:

Sender side:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long firstLong;
    char   firstStr[32];
    double firstDouble;
    etc...
} custom_data_type;


int main()
{
    // initialize two pointers, one pointing to the struct and the other to a string identifier
    custom_data_type data_info;
    memset (&data_info,0, sizeof(custom_data_type));
    char * str_id = ".sid";

    // Get the combined size of two pointers
    int size = sizeof(custom_data_type) + strlen(str_id);

    char * ptr = malloc(size); // I tried using a void pointer but it didn't allow pointer arithmetic, so using a char pointer here
    
    memcpy(ptr, &data_info, sizeof(custom_data_type));  // ptr should first point to the custom data type
    memcpy((ptr+sizeof(custom_data_type)), str_id, strlen(str_id)); // ptr should point to the string ID where custome data type memory block ends
    // the end result here is that the pointer variable ptr will point to the memory location
    // containing custom_data_type, appended right after with a char pointer containing ".sid"
    // The memory block pointed to by ptr here is what the receiver will get
}
```

And on the receiver's end, I could have the code read data & recognize the string ID like this:

```
if(strcmp(ptr+sizeof(custom_data_type), ".sid") == 0 )
{
     // string identifier found; we've received custom_data_type from the router
}
else
{
     // No string identifier found, assume the received data is NOT custom_data_type
}
```

The socket communication function between the sender & receiver takes as arguments a void pointer and the size of memory pointed by it.

I've never really done much coding related to socket communication, so I'm mostly curious if the above code will work in theory.

Comment: I think you're discovering the importance of [framing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(networking)) in data transmission. I'd strongly suggest putting the framing first, not last, so you can look at the stream and know what to expect, not *guess* that it'll appear N bytes in.

Comment: Don't forget the NULL of a NULL terminated string or use strncmp().

Comment: Careful with `strcmp(ptr+sizeof(custom_data_type), ".sid")` - *as is*, you have stripped the null terminating byte.

Comment: Also, if you're sending a struct as a binary object, you need to be careful it has the padding you expect. You can use offsetof() to make sure the elements are where you think they should be. There are also endianness issues to consider.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp(ptr+sizeof(custom_data_type), ".sid")` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as `custom_data_type` is not certainly a *string*.  It does not clearly have a *null character* appended, necessary for it to be a *string*.

**Allocate better**

Allocate for a *null character* too.  Use `size_t` math for allocations.

```
// int size = sizeof(custom_data_type) + strlen(str_id);
size_t str_id_size = strlen(str_id) + 1;
size_t size = sizeof(custom_data_type) + str_id_size;
```

Copy the null character.

```
// memcpy((ptr+sizeof(custom_data_type)), str_id, strlen(str_id));
memcpy((ptr+sizeof(custom_data_type)), str_id, str_id_size);
```